# How to draw plane shapes in TeX

Tags: pdftex, diagrams

I wish to draw some explanatory figures in LaTeX. A typical example is what I have in the figure below. I tried it out on Geogebra but wasn't successful. Could anyone give me a hint?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  The question mentions LaTeX explicitly, so I removed the "tex-core" tag, and added "diagrams", which refers to pictures drawn within the LaTeX job.

Comment: Thank you, Barbara

Comment: If my answer solved the problem, then consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- This might get you started.
- [`pgfplots`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) is a famous LaTeX package, have a look at the examples from the manual (http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html).
- It can get (very) complex if you want to control every little aspect.

> "PGFPlots draws high-quality function plots in normal or logarithmic
>   scaling with a user-friendly interface directly in TeX."

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

% http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=-3,   
    xmax=3,
    ymin=-3,   
    ymax=3,
    axis y line = middle,
    axis x line = middle,
]
    \addplot [data cs=polar,domain=0:360, no marks, densely dotted] (\x,1);
    \addplot [only marks,mark=*, red] coordinates {
        (0,0) 
        (1,1)
        };
    \addplot [only marks,mark=*, blue] coordinates {
        (3,3) 
        (-2,-3)
        };      
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfectly helpful..Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Simply with `\draw` command in in `tikzpicture` library :

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
  \draw (1,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Source : [LaTeX/PGF/TikZ](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/PGF/TikZ)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how are you getting this data, but if you are adding dots manually, I believe `fit` and `shapes.geometric` libraries from `tikz` could be helpful:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes.geometric}

\tikzset{%
bdot/.style={circle, draw, fill=blue, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=4pt},
rdot/.style={circle, draw, fill=red, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=4pt}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (-3,0) -- (3,0);
    \draw (0,3) -- (0,-3);
    \node[bdot] (b1) at (1,1) {};
    \node[bdot] (b2) at (0.5,-0.2) {};
    \node[ellipse, draw=black, fit=(b1) (b2), inner sep=1mm] {};
    \node[rdot] (r1) at (1,3) {};
    \node[rdot] (r2) at (-2,1) {};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

gives the following result

[image]